# Fetch all addresses holding an ERC20 token at a given timestamp

Tags: python, blockchain, ethereum, erc20, etherscan

I am trying to figure out how to do the following [in Python]:

- Fetch the address of all wallets holding a given ERC20 before a given date.

EG: 'Get holdingAddresses from contractAddress before timestamp'

I've looked at both the Ethplorer and Etherscan API's and I cannot figure out a way to retrieve this data.

I think the answer may be through Infura, but I'm at a loss on where to start there if that is indeed the solution.

Anyone know if this can be done, and if so - how?!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example [how to get all token transfers with web3.py](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#advanced-example-fetching-all-token-transfer-events).

You store the data locally, like in an SQL database. You can construct the list token holdings at a point of time, based on the transfers that happened before the block number of the timestamp. You just have a maximum block number and do not query any `Transfer` events after that block number.